# How to get around multidimensional arrays in BASH?

Tags: arrays, bash, sorting, multidimensional-array, sh

I am using bash to create program that:

1. Takes the user input for a person's name and their quarterly sales figure and puts them into separate arrays.
2. The user is then given an option to sort either alphabetically by name or numerically by their sales figure.

   I need a way of making sure that both the name and the respective quarterly sales figure are in the same index on each array after sorting (as I'm aware BASH doesn't support multi-dimensional arrays).

This is the code I've used for storing the data in an array:

```
function getData() 
{
     read -p "Number of sales people: " spAmount    
     for (( i=0; i<$spAmount; i++ ))
     do
         read -p "Please enter a sales persons name:" salesPeople[i]
         read -p "Please enter their quarterly sales: " quarterlySales[i]
     done
}
```

This is the code used for sorting the arrays (using bubble sort method):

```
function sortData()
{
for (( q = 0; q < $spAmount ; q++ ))
do
    for (( p = $q; p < $spAmount; p++ ))
    do
        if [[ ${salesPeople[q]} > ${salesPeople[$p]} ]]
        then
            r=${salesPeople[q]}
            salesPeople[$q]=${salesPeople[$p]}
            salesPeople[$p]=$r
        fi
    done
done

for (( i = 0; i < $spAmount ; i++ ))
do
    for (( j = $i; j < $spAmount; j++ ))
    do
        if [ ${quarterlySales[i]} -gt ${quarterlySales[$j]}  ]
        then
            k=${quarterlySales[i]}
            quarterlySales[$i]=${quarterlySales[$j]}
            quarterlySales[$j]=$k
        fi
    done
done
```

}

I thought I might be able to combine both inputs into one string like "foo#bar" and use a string command or regex to get the variable before or after the hashtag? Not sure how this would work exactly though.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason  you are using `bash` and not a more suitable language for this?

Comment: If you want the `foo#bar` structure you described, I believe you know how to change `getData`. You then basically need to change only the `if` statements like this: `${salesPeople[i]#*#}` to compare by `bar` and `{salesPeople[i]%#*}` to compare only by `foo`. Hope it helped :)

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays#Associative_Arrays-1

Comment: It's for an assignment that's why I've got to use `bash`.  So the `${salesPeople[i]#*#}` will allow me to just grab the string after the hashtag (which would be `bar`) correct?  Thank you!

Comment: @D'Arcy Yep, it's called parameter expansion. You can read more about it here: [http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal).